# full adder with two half adder in quartus ii

Tags: quartus

I am new in quartus. one of my home work was to implement a full adder with two half adder in quartus. now I created half adder but I don't know how to use it in other schematic file to implement full adder.
thanks.

Comment: This should probably go to Electrical Engineering SE, as this is not a programming question. Anyway, to answer you a half adder appears to be an adder lacking carry input. So you'd want to [use a trick involving two half adders in series in order to simulate a full adder](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_4/chpt_9/3.html). In practice nobody would ever want to do that, as this would increase the propagation delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export your half adder to a `.bdf` file (`File` > `Create/Update` > `Create Symbol Files for Current File`) and then use it as a symbol (i.e. just like other gates) in another schematic files.